# Putting a :map property on an image

Tags: image, emacs, elisp

I'm trying to insert an image in emacs like this:

```
(defun image-wipe-and-insert ()
  (interactive)
  (let ()
    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*an image area test buffer*")
      (switch-to-buffer (current-buffer))
      (erase-buffer)
      (insert-image (find-image '((:type png :file "/usr/share/emacs/24.4/etc/images/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/emacs.png"
                     :map  '((rect . ((0 . 0) . (50 . 50))) anAreaID (:pointer hourglass :help-echo "You found an area!"))
                     ;; :relief -20
                     ;; :conversion laplace
                     :margin (0 . 0)
                     :pointer arrow)))))))
```

This kind of works, and seems to create an area in the top right corner (also works for mouse clicks). But I have two problems with the `:map` property:

1. (How) can I specify more than one rectangle?
2. The values in the extra properties, `:help-echo` and `:pointer`, seem to have no effect. Is the syntax wrong?

The info node I think is relevant is here: `info:elisp#Image Descriptors` (= http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Image-Descriptors.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As it says, an image `:map` value is an *alist*.  Your example uses a single element.
2. The correct attributes are `help-echo` and `pointer` (no colon)

   ```
   (defun image-wipe-and-insert ()
     (interactive)
     (let ()
       (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*an image area test buffer*")
         (switch-to-buffer (current-buffer))
         (erase-buffer)
         (insert-image
          (find-image '((:type png
                 :file "icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/emacs.png"
                 :map (((rect . ((0 . 0) . (50 . 50)))
                    area1
                    (pointer hourglass
                     help-echo "You found the first area!"))
                   ((rect . ((50 . 50) . (100 . 100)))
                    area2
                    (pointer hand
                     help-echo "You found the second area!")))
                 :margin (2 . 2)
                 :pointer arrow)))))))
   ```

Comment: Right you are, thanks! A slightly different answer (adding an explicit call to list) was given here: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2015-05/msg00226.html